# Display text corresponding to Combobox selection in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, vba

I have a contact form and one of the fields in a the form is a Contact_Type_ID. This field is a number field which also corresponds to a text field in another table (e.g. 1 = expatriate).

When I cycle through the contacts, their Contact_Type_ID is 1, 2, 3... instead of Non-profit, CEO, Vice-president, etc. This is a problem because one has no idea what number 3 means.

I would like to a combobox that only displays the corresponding text.

I can't get the two columns and 0;1 format to work. My hunch is that it's because I'm drawing information from two different tables. I can generate the correct list, but then the main entry doesn't change as I cycle through the contacts to reflect the current contact's [Contact_Type_ID].

I can't edit any of the current tables because I am supposed to apply this application to a much larger scale database.

I also tried setting the SQL for the row source:

```
'Populate the connection combo box '
Dim typeSQL As String
typeSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Contacts.[ContactTypeID], Contact_Types.[ContactType] " & _
    "FROM Contacts, Contact_Types " & _
    "ORDER BY Contact_Types.[ContactType];"
Me.cbo_ContactType.RowSource = typeSQL
```

However, I then have the same problem: the combobox won't update as I cycle through the contacts. I don't understand the difference between the rowsource and the controlsource. I feel that this distinction might be key here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly:

In the combo box properties, go to the `Data` tab.
Set the `Control Source` to `Contact_Type_ID`.

This means that when you go through the records, the combo box will correspond to the Contact_Type_ID field from your data.

Set the `Row Source` to `"SELECT Contacts.[ContactTypeID], Contact_Types.[ContactType] FROM Contacts, Contact_Types ORDER BY Contact_Types.[ContactType];"`

The Row Source indicates the data that the combo box has access to, which will help it determine how to display the control source value.

Set the `Bound Column` to `1`

Set `Limit to List` to `Yes`

Now in the `Format` tab. Change `Column Count` to `2`.
Next set the `column widths` to the `0;1` you mentioned in your question.

Now try looking at form view, and it should behave as you expected.

If it does not work, create a new control with [these instructions.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-list-of-choices-by-using-a-list-box-or-combo-box-HA010113052.aspx#BMusewizard)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you have a form with contacts based on a table `Contacts` and that table contains a field called either `Contact_Type_ID` or `ContactTypeID`. You wish to display the description of the contact type from a table `Contact_Types`.

You do not need to join tables for your combo, it should be very simple. The key, as you suspected, is the `Control source`, which is the property that relates one table to another.

```
Control source : ContactTypeID '' or Contact_Type_ID, choose from the list
Row source : SELECT ContactTypeID, ContactType FROM Contact_Types ORDER BY ContactType
Bound column : 1
Column count : 2
Column widths : 0,2
```

As an aside, you can join tables in a combo and still set the first column to 0 and it will still work, it is all in the correct set up.

Comment: Alright, I got it to work in the end. I needed to learn more about Cartesian products. Thank you!